# Flexbox issue in Safari browser

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I raised this question before, but had few commentaries that the format of the question was incorrect, so I want to give it another try.

I experience issue with my flexbox in Safari Browser. The `.div` `.memeber-card` inside my `section` overlapping when preview the page in Safari browser.

I used an Autoprefixer website, which was recommended to me on this site, but this did not fix the issue.

Can some one have a quick look at my css, and tell me, what is the issue for Safari Browser?

```
section {
  color: aliceblue;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.members {
  width: 50%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.member-card {
  padding: 2%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 21%;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 21%;
          flex-basis: 21%;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}


.member-image {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
  text-align: center;
  max-width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}


.team-body {
background-image:
-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, whitesmoke, rgba(255,255,255,0) 99%), url('../img/team-2-page.jpg');
background-image:
linear-gradient(0deg, whitesmoke, rgba(255,255,255,0) 99%), url('../img/team-2-page.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 100% 0%;
}

/****Nav***/

.teamnav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.teamnav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.teamnav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px 0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: "Pontano Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

[Safari browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD8a.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today. 
I fixed it using a basis with a absolute size like 200px.

Maybe try something like this:

`.member-card {
  flex-basis: 200px;
}`